# Python's "make install" still references the source files

Tags: python, virtualenv

For testing my libraries on multiple Python versions I have a single virtual environment that I install them into, and reference them with their complete name/version (i.e. python3.7).  Recently I noticed that `sys.path` is still referencing the source library instead of the copied library (i.e. `/source/python/...` instead of `/source/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/...`)

I've tried `make install` instead of `make altinstall` <sup>1</sup>, I've searched for answers -- so far nothing has helped.

How do I fix this?

---

<sup>1</sup> PSA: If you use `make (alt)install` and you don't want to clobber your system Python, make sure and use

```
./configure --prefix /path/to/install_to/here
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**  Remove the `pyvenv.cfg` in the virtualenv root directory.

---

The issue is the interaction with the virtualenv, and not `make`.  Somewhere in Python's startup it checks to see if it is running in a virtualenv and, if it is, uses the libraries from it's original installation (and I had created the virtualenv from my source copy).

The solution is to remove the `pyvenv.cfg` file in the root of the virtualenv.  This will completely isolate the virtualenv from the system (so no sharing of site-packages nor dist-packages), but is exactly what I wanted for my purposes.